# Google+ link for YouTube channel creates 2 channels?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, account-management, google-account

Using another Google account—`myname@gmail.com`—, I created a YouTube channel named DJTheLQ. Recently I was asked if I wanted to link this to Google+. I said yes and clicked all the options (don't remember exactly what) that would essentially leave my channel name as DJTheLQ.

However, now I'm stuck with 2 completely separate channels that I have to manually switch ever time in the channel selector: `myname@gmail.com` and DJTheLQ. I don't want this since I'm never going to use the `myname@gmail.com` one and don't like that I have to manually switch to the other channel whenever I switch to that Google account.

Is it possible to have one Google Account with

- Only 1 channel named DJTheLQ
- Only 1 Google Account Page named DJTheLQ

Answer (score 1):

**Useful advice for YouTube and Google+ integration and unlinking a YT channel from Peggy K:**

When you create a YouTube channel you currently have the option to create it with a Google+ Profile identity or a Google+ Page identity. If you choose the option to use a "real name" Google+ Profile identity, you can later unlink your YouTube channel from Google+ and (if you choose) link it to a Google+ Page representing your YouTube identity, brand, business or organization.

Be aware that if you create your YouTube channel using a "business or other name", linking it to a Google+ Page, your YouTube channel and its Page cannot be unlinked.

Here is the brief summary of how to unlink your YouTube channel from its Google+ Profile if you don't want to use your real name identity:

https://plus.google.com/103172072345300450419/posts/EbqhQTgsA1o